# "design" vs. "designing"

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to describe Steve jobs with the following sentence.

> His **design** marries art with function, such as iPhone, iPad, MacBook Air.

There are two [meanings of "design" on the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/design) are related.

> the art of making plans or drawings for something

> the way in which something is planned and made

The former is also a synonym of "designing".

Which one should I go with?

In other words, does this one have the same meaning?

> His designing marries art with function, such as iPhone, iPad, MacBook Air.

---

**Note:** The example sentence I made up at the beginning is to describe the way/art Steve jobs designed products in general, rather than the design of any specific product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a native English speaker, I would recommend using "design" instead of "designing" here.

This sentence needs a noun to use as a subject for what "marries art with function" (the prime verb here being "marries"), and while "designing" also becomes a gerund that acts as a noun, simply using the root "design" is more direct. Simpler is usually better for language/grammar choices.

There is also a slight issue with tense here, as Steve Jobs has passed away. Using the gerund "designing" makes it seem as if he is still producing work which could confuse the reader.

I think this is a nit, where neither is incredibly obviously wrong and the meaning is, as you thought, very similar, but I would definitely give preference to "design."

Comment: Thank you. Does this discussion involve AmE vs. BrE?

Comment: I'm American, so I use AmE. A quick Google on differences in usage of gerunds in AmE and BrE didn't get me much, though, so it's likely this case has the same issue in both.

Comment: (+1) I think there is more than just a syntactic reason to use "design" instead of the gerund "designing": the latter seems to attribute the description (that it "marries art with function") to his _act_, _method_ or _process_ of designing rather than to the _product_ of his designing, i.e. his design. That meaning may still fit, but it fits, as you said, less directly.

Comment: @RobertH: I'm a Brit, and I endorse this answer.

Comment: "His designs marry […]"?

Comment: Given the context, "design" should be "designs" as the statement appears to be about multiple designs.

Answer (score 2):

If I'd read "design", I would first think of him as an artificially constructed humanoid, which was really well designed (as if "the way in which something is planned and made" is referred to him). Maybe you can find a way around this ambiguity, like "The way he designed [...]", "His way of designing [...]" or just "His designs", as suggested in the comments.

Comment: "His design" could mean "The design made by him" or "The design of him". You interpreted it as the latter, but the former makes much more sense here (although it should probably be a plural).

Comment: @NotThatGuy I know, both meanings are provided in the question. I'm trying to find a solution where this semantic ambiguity is resolved, so no misinterpretation for the piece of information to be transmitted will be possible.

Comment: Alternatively, we could boil down "his way of designing" to "his design philosophy."